# Enterpise mode on a domain, but want some pages to use Edge mode

Tags: angularjs, asp-classic, compatibility, microsoft-edge

Our company told users to use enterprise mode for a particular site which is Classic ASP.  It uses framesets - one page holding the menu and another with the content.

We are trying to upgrade the site and have introduced a new MVC page within the frameset (content frame) which requires Angular which doesn't work with Enterprise mode.

I've tried to set the new page to use edge () to no avail.  So I guess it doesn't affect it.

Short of fixing the Classic ASP's issues (dropdowns, disabled buttons, next & previous buttons) and ridding ourselves of enterprise mode are there any fixes I should consider?

Comment: How did you instruct the page to use the "edge" document mode?

Comment: The frameset cannot have the meta tag (<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">) in it as we only want some pages to use  edge mode.  The inner MVC page starts as following :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> but that doesn't work.

Comment: Correct, you cannot have a sub-resource (within a frame) be in Edge mode, while the parent document is in an earlier document mode.

Comment: Would I be correct in thinking that if the user decides to use Enterprise mode that there is nothing that can be done on the site to override this?

Comment: Enterprise Mode emulates IE 8, which would prevent you from having any Edge Document Mode resources.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the end was to let the users know that enterprise mode will no longer work.